# Firebase Domain Whitelist not working for sendEmailVerification

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, whitelist

In my onboarding work-flow, I'm trying to verify a newly created user's email with this code *(as per example in the docs)*

```
verifyEmail(): firebase.Promise<any> {

    const actionCodeSettings: firebase.auth.ActionCodeSettings = {
      url: 'http://localhost:4200/main/profile',
      handleCodeInApp: false
    };

    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings);
  }
```

Unfortunately, the result of the promise is this error:

```
{code: "auth/unauthorized-continue-uri", message: "Domain not whitelisted by project"}
```

However, in Firebase console, 'localhost' **is** whitelisted (by default). If I change localhost by my current IP, which is also whitelisted, it doesn't work either.

Here is the request from Chrome Dev tools:

```
Request URL:https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getOobConfirmationCode?key=blahblahblah
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 
Request Payload:
{
    "requestType":"VERIFY_EMAIL",
    "idToken":"blahblahblahblah",
    "continueUrl":"https://localhost:4200/main/profile",
    "canHandleCodeInApp":false
}
```

And this is my Firebase console:
[image]

Looks like a bug but wanted to be sure before raising an issue to Firebase  guys.

**Any thoughts?**

Comment: And your firebase environment is correctly set up and loaded in your ngModule? https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md#4-add-firebase-config-to-environments-variable

Comment: Yep, correctly set-up.
I successfully login with Google/Facebook/email as well as create a new user through email (hence the email verification process).

Comment: There may be a bug with domain checks that contain non default port numbers. I am assuming you are using localhost for testing only. Try to test with your production domain.

Comment: I am able to replicate it. Seems like a bug in domain matching when port numbers are provided.

Comment: @bojeil yes, localhost is for development only. I don't have a prod environment yet. Maybe I could use Firebase hosting capacities to try. 
Also, I'm surprise this issue has never been raised before, as I'm just doing a "by the book" app using angular 4 and localhost:4200 is the default url for "ng serve". Looks like nobody test their code :-p
Thanks for the help

Comment: @bojeil, should I open an issue on git? If it's the case, what project would you recommend?

Comment: I have already filed this issue on your behalf. The fix should be in within 2 weeks. I will keep you posted.

Comment: For others who have this problem with a domain name make sure to also include 2 domains one with www and without. I came in this post with a similar problem and realized I couldn't get whitelisting to work with my domains since my code had 'www' in the url. -- Just leaving this comment here in case anyone has a similar issue to this

Comment: Adding a domain with a port still doesn't work

Comment: @bojeil do you know if this got fixed? Still seems to be a problem

Comment: Never mind. Its fine. I misunderstood what I was meant to be whitelisting. I thought it was the domain I'm calling the API from not the domain of the page I'm redirecting to

Comment: @Jonathan002 Thanks for the fix that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

For others who have this problem with a domain name make sure to also
include 2 domains one with `www` and without.

Credit to [Jonathan002](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3859456/jonathan002)

Comment: Instantly fixed my issue 